# What counts towards weapon skill?

Tags: battlefield-4

What actions in game count towards your skill with a given weapon? For example, I can get 408 points in a round for a weapon, which indicates it's not simply the 100pts per kill being applied to the stat.

My assumption is kill assist points also apply. Does anything else?

Comment: using XP boost also contributes to your weapon skill points earned too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only speak from my personal experience, but I have observed that kills and assists are the only sources of xp counted for weapons. Other experience (spot bonus, etc) seems to go towards leveling the class you are on.

Comment: what about supression?

Comment: @turbo I can't tell for sure yet

Comment: This seems to fit with what I've observed too. It would be nice to have a more official list though. Thanks!